# Rate Limiting Outgoing via Relay Host

Tags: postfix

How do I get per domain rate limiting in Postfix?

I have a Postfix server that's behind a relay host. The relay host is our MS Exchange bridge. The relay does not perform any throttling, nor will it complain that I'm sending too much too fast.

I have rate limiting enabled, but it is introducing a 1s delay between every email, not just 1s between every email per domain.

My expectation is that the gmail.com, att.net, and one of the yahoo.com addresses (from the following log snippet) would send within
the same second; and that the next yahoo.com address would send in the next tick.

Here's a snippet of the log:

```
May 31 11:39:34 postfix_machine postfix/smtp[16117]: 1DCB881D59C4: to=<...@gmail.com>, relay=relayhost_ip_addr[relayhost_ip_addr]:25, conn_use=93, delay=6195, delays=0.03/6195/0.08/0.33, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20220531135619.1DCB881D59C4@postfix_machine.example.com> [InternalId=115998476732199, Hostname=relayhost_domain_name] 19717 bytes in 0.168, 114.157 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
May 31 11:39:34 postfix_machine postfix/qmgr[2141]: 1DCB881D59C4: removed
May 31 11:39:35 postfix_machine postfix/smtp[16117]: 404AB81D59C7: to=<...@gmail.com>, relay=relayhost_ip_addr[relayhost_ip_addr]:25, conn_use=94, delay=6197, delays=0.02/6196/0.07/0.32, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20220531135619.404AB81D59C7@postfix_machine.example.com> [InternalId=115998476732200, Hostname=relayhost_domain_name] 19721 bytes in 0.167, 115.117 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
May 31 11:39:35 postfix_machine postfix/qmgr[2141]: 404AB81D59C7: removed
May 31 11:39:37 postfix_machine postfix/smtp[16117]: 6444581D59CA: to=<...@yahoo.com>, relay=relayhost_ip_addr[relayhost_ip_addr]:25, conn_use=95, delay=6198, delays=0.02/6197/0.07/0.32, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20220531135619.6444581D59CA@postfix_machine.example.com> [InternalId=115998476732201, Hostname=relayhost_domain_name] 19719 bytes in 0.168, 114.247 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
May 31 11:39:37 postfix_machine postfix/qmgr[2141]: 6444581D59CA: removed
May 31 11:39:38 postfix_machine postfix/smtp[16117]: 8792E81D59CD: to=<...@yahoo.com>, relay=relayhost_ip_addr[relayhost_ip_addr]:25, conn_use=96, delay=6199, delays=0.02/6199/0.07/0.32, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20220531135619.8792E81D59CD@postfix_machine.example.com> [InternalId=115998476732202, Hostname=relayhost_domain_name] 19718 bytes in 0.168, 114.377 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
May 31 11:39:38 postfix_machine postfix/qmgr[2141]: 8792E81D59CD: removed
May 31 11:39:40 postfix_machine postfix/smtp[16117]: AB92E81D59D0: to=<...@att.net>, relay=relayhost_ip_addr[relayhost_ip_addr]:25, conn_use=97, delay=6200, delays=0.02/6200/0.07/0.32, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20220531135619.AB92E81D59D0@postfix_machine.example.com> [InternalId=115998476732203, Hostname=relayhost_domain_name] 19715 bytes in 0.168, 114.593 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
May 31 11:39:40 postfix_machine postfix/qmgr[2141]: AB92E81D59D0: removed
```

Here's the configurations I have that deviate from the defaults:

```
compatibility_level = 2

inet_protocols = all

mynetworks_style = host

header_size_limit = 4096000
message_size_limit = 0
mailbox_size_limit = 0

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

smtputf8_enable = no
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

relayhost = [relayhost_ip_addr]:25

smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 10
smtp_connection_reuse_count_limit = 100

smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```